# How can I reset data in child component from parent component on vue.js 2?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

My parent component like this :

```
<template> 
    <div ref="modal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content modal-content-data">
                <form id="form-data">
                    ...
                    <location-select .../>
                    ...
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import LocationSelect from './LocationSelect.vue'
    export default{
        name: 'CartModal',
        components:{
            LocationSelect,
        },
        mounted(){
            $(this.$refs.modal).on('hidden.bs.modal', () => {
                Object.assign(this.$data, this.$options.data())
            })
        }
    }
</script>
```

If modal hidden, it will reset data in parent component and it works

I want to reset data also in child component

I try like this :

```
<template>
    <select class="form-control" v-model="selected" ...>
        ...
    </select>
</template>
<script>
    export default{
        name: 'LocationSelect',
        ...
        created() {
            $(this.$parent.$refs.modal).on('hidden.bs.modal', () => {
                Object.assign(this.$data, this.$options.data())
            })
        }
    };
</script>
```

But it does not work

The child component no reset the data

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Pass the data using props. Then you can have control on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem with this code is the handler in `LocationSelect` is being added *before* `this.$parent.$refs.modal` exists. A `ref` does not exist until the component is mounted.

The easiest way to solve this would be to move the code to `mounted`.

```
mounted() {
  $(this.$parent.$refs.modal).on('hidden.bs.modal', () => {
    Object.assign(this.$data, this.$options.data())
  })
}
```

Or you could leave it in `created` and use `nextTick`.

```
created() {
  this.$nextTick(() => {
    $(this.$parent.$refs.modal).on('hidden.bs.modal', () => {
      Object.assign(this.$data, this.$options.data())
    })
  })
}
```

Another way to handle this would be to add a `ref` to the `LocationSelect` component and add a method that clears it that can be called from the parent. In `LocationSelect` add this method:

```
methods:{
  clear(){
    Object.assign(this.$data, this.$options.data())
  }
}
```

In the parent template add a ref:

```
<location-select ref="locationSelect" ... />
```

And in your parent's mounted:

```
mounted(){
  $(this.$refs.modal).on('hidden.bs.modal', () => {
    Object.assign(this.$data, this.$options.data())
    this.$refs.locationSelect.clear()
  })
}
```

However, **the most idiomatic way to handle this with Vue** would be to modify the component to support `v-model` and then it would be automatically cleared when the parent is cleared.

```
<template>
    <select class="form-control" v-model="selected" ...>
        ...
    </select>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: ["value"],
        name: 'LocationSelect',
        computed:{
          selected:{
            get(){ return this.value },
            set(v) { this.$emit('input', v) }
          }
        },
    };
</script>
```

And then in the parent template:

```
<location-select v-model="someDataValue" ... />
```

If you did this, then when the parent is clear, the child is automatically cleared as well.

Comment: Why would you use `nexttick` in `created` rather than moving it to `mounted`?

Comment: @RoyJ Child mounted fires before parent mounted. See here. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/dVbzJg?editors=1010

Comment: @RoyJ But the $ref *does* appear to exist at that point in the parent...

Comment: Do you still have some leftover old answer in your revised answer?

Comment: @RoyJ Probably a confusing sentence or two. Updated.

Comment: @Bert, If I do : `console.log(this.$parent.$refs.modal)` in child component on the `created`, on the console `undefined`.

Comment: @SuccessMan Yes, in *created* of the child component, that will be undefined.

Comment: @Bert, Okay. I try use `ref`. I had follow your step above, but on the console exist error : `Uncaught TypeError: this$1.$refs.locationSelect.clear is not a function`

Comment: @SuccessMan First, let me suggest you go with the code you posted in your original question and change `created` in LocationSelect to `mounted`. If that doesn't work for you, please post your new code.

Comment: @Bert, If I change `created` to be `mounted`, it works. But I also try you another solution. I try `ref` and there exist error

Comment: @SuccessMan DId you add the `clear` method to LocationSelect?

Comment: @Bert, Yes, I had add it

Comment: @SuccessMan Here is a [basic example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/XerYbY?editors=1010). If you can't see the difference between this and your code, post your code somewhere and I'll review it.

Comment: @Bert, Okay. Thanks a lot for your help